# How to insert null in NUMBER column in table

Tags: oracle

There is a below statement in my stored procedure

```
QUERY := 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE set MGRID=' || V_ID ||
         ' WHERE OTHER_ID=''' || V1_ID || ''' and  CODE=''ABC''';
```

Here V_ID is NUMBER(30) variable which has null value, now i want to insert NULL in MGRID when i do as above it throws ORA-00936: missing expression. Because it treats V_ID as blank and form SQL like below

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE set MGRID= WHERE OTHER_ID....
```

Please let me know how i can insert null in MGRID.

Comment: Consider bind variables.  Otherwise, simplest version, .... set MGRId = NULL ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably could use `nvl` in this case...

```
 QUERY := 'UPDATE EMPLOYEE set MGRID=' || nvl(to_char(V_ID),'NULL') || ' WHERE OTHER_ID=''' || V1_ID || ''' and  CODE=''ABC''';
```

In any case, one should be careful with this kind of statements as they are prone to `sql injection`...

Comment: it giving below error : SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal  Try my edited version - just added `to_char` ... to avoid probable `invalid number`...

Comment: Yes it worked now thanks a lot, but why previously it was giving invalid number and how to_char resolved it can you please explain.

Comment: also if V_ID is not null and have a number will it work in that case also ?

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal Ok, glad it worked. Now, regarding your questions - look up the `nvl` function  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm). It didn't work at first because one argument was number and the other char - with `to_char` we solved that. `Nvl` transforms only `null` values, so if `v_id` has non-null value - it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Use variable binding to avoid each-time query compilation:

```
`execute immediate
         'Update employee set MGRID = :V_ID where OTHERE_ID = :V1_ID and CODE = ''ABC'''
         using V_ID, V1ID;`
```